# How to find regional settings on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an c# application on Windows Phone and its critical to know the date settings.
I mean if the month is first and the day is second (01/31/2014) or the day is first and the month second (31/01/2014)
How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to find the system culture and `DateTimeFormatInfo`

```
DateTimeFormatInfo formatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
```

Comment: And which is the Property to find if the First is the month or the day?

Comment: You can parse that information from `DateTimeFormatInfo.LongDatePattern`

Comment: I used the ShortDatePatern because LongDatePattern always have the day first